# How to break line in authors affiliation of the academic papers?

Tags: align, line-breaking, elsarticle, affiliation

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref} 
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor Gro-zev}


\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title of the paper}

\author[rvt,rvt2]{Ricardo Ramos de Oliveira\corref{cor2}}
\ead{ricardoramos@icmc.usp.br}

\author[rvt]{Victor Hugo Santiago Costa Pinto\corref{cor1}}
\ead{victor.santiago@usp.br}

\author[rvt]{Helder Jefferson Ferreira da Luz\corref{cor1}}
\ead{helderfl@icmc.usp.br}

\author[rvt]{Adenilso da Silva Sim\~ao\corref{cor1}}
\ead{adenilso@icmc.usp.br}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author}

\address[rvt]{Institute of Mathematical and Computer Sciences}

\address[rvt2]{Federal Institute of Education.}

\begin{abstract}

Abstract of the paper

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
keyword of the paper
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

Contents of the paper.

\end{document}
```

The result of this code is:

[image]

How should I do to put the **third name** in the second line and add the **and** as per the following figure.

[image]